# How do i randomly rotate point instances with either 90, 180, 270 or 360 degrees?

Tags: geometry-nodes

How do i randomly rotate point instances with either 90, 180, 270 or 360 degrees?

When using attribute randomize, and choosing `rotation` as the attribute, I cannot achieve this result.

Comment: Why do you want to rotate something by 360°? (360=0) Is it animated? You can calculate a random number (0,1,2,3) and multiply it by 90.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

---

**Geometry Nodes fields solution**

With this node setup:

[image]

You will get this:

[image]

How it works:

It generates a random number (integer) from 0 to 3.

This will be multiplied with pi/2 (which is 90 degrees in radians) and so you will always get an angle of 0, 90, 180 or 270 degrees.

---

**2.9x Geometry Nodes** (outdated)

In 2.9x You can for instance use an [Attribute Randomize](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/2.92/modeling/geometry_nodes/attribute/attribute_randomize.html) node set to *Integer* after your [Point Distribute](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/modeling/geometry_nodes/point/point_distribute.html) node, type in `rotation` as the attribute, Min value of 0 and max value of 3.

This will fill the rotation parameter of each point instance with random vectors containing integers between 0 and 3.

Afterwards, use an [Attribute Vector Math](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/modeling/geometry_nodes/attribute/attribute_vector_math.html) node set to *Multiply*. Set *A* and *Result* to rotation, because we want to use the previous data to set the final rotation. Change the type of *B* to *Vector*, and set it to [0, 0, 1.5708] (or type `pi/2` in the field for better precision).

What we just did with these two nodes is setup a random integer between 0 and 3 for each point instance, and use this integer to be multiplied by $π/2$ :

- $0 * π /2 = 0 rad ≡ 0° ≡ 360°$
- $1 * π /2 = π/2 rad ≡ 90°$
- $2 * π /2 = π rad ≡ 180°$
- $3 * π /2 = 3π/2 rad ≡ 270°$

Result:

[image]

Note : We are doing it that way because if you just set the Attribute Randomize node to a minimum of 0 and maximum of 3π/2 (270°), it would possibly randomly generate all the possible rational numbers between 0 and 3π/2, and not numbers at fixed intervals.

If you wanted to do it that way, you could use this setup with the Vector Math node set to *Snap* to the closest increment of $(0, 0, pi/2)$.

[image]

Comment: Ah, π does the trick. And there is a node that works as a random number generator. Good to know :)

Comment: Out of interest can this be done via align to vectors `(0, 1), (1, 0), (0, -1), (-1, 0)`

Comment: @batFINGER I wouldn't know how to do that efficiently in GN...

Comment: +1 for maintaining the answer to even fit to the new GN :D