# Is there any way to randomly rotate invidividual particles either 90, 180, 270, or 360 degrees along one axis?

Tags: particles, geometry-nodes, particle-nodes

I'm a beginner at Blender, and I was trying to make a Tetris themed thing. For it, I wanted to have each individual piece be randomly rotated 90, 180, 270, or 360 degrees on the Z axis. Is there any way I could do that? So far, I have these nodes, which get a random arrangement by position for the pieces, but not by rotation. I tried to plug in the "Value" from the Multiply Node into Rotation for "Instance on Points", which didn't work since it had each kind of piece for the 7 pieces rotate across the X, Y, and Z axes a random amount (i.e. all of the L pieces tilted the same random amount):

[image]

Answer (score 5):

with this node setup:

[image]

you will get this:

[image]

How it works:

it generates a random number (integer) from 0 to 3.

This will be multiplied with pi/2 (which is 90 degrees in radians) and so you will always get an angle of 0, 90, 180 or 270 degrees.

Comment: I don't really know what to do here since https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/230339/how-do-i-randomly-rotate-point-instances-with-either-90-180-270-or-360-degrees/230344 is an exact duplicate but the solution I provided isn't relevant anymore with the fields workflow. Maybe repost your answer there too and link the two Q&A? But +1 of course

Comment: @Gorgious: i added it to your question so everything is in one place...makes more sense to me. And maybe you got even more reputation ;) Hope that's fine with you.

Comment: Sure that's alright thanks ! You got me a bronze badge actually ^^I just moved your fields solution first because I think the 2.9 solution will be less and less relevant in the future. Cheers